# How to change the look of OK and Cancel Buttons

Tags: buttons, themes

I know I can change the look of some elements using a different launcher, 
But how do I change how the OK or Cancel buttons look?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to install a custom theme using the T-Mobile theme chooser (it comes built into [CyanogenMod](http://cyanogenmod.com)). There is no way to do this in stock without modding your ROM.